# Retrofit2 cant access to arrays in POJO

Tags: java, android, json, retrofit2

I want to pass data from JSON array to display it in RecyclerView but in logcat there is "Items = 0". Any solution?

> D/RestauransActivity: response = {"controller":"RestaurantController","info":"Restaurants found!","restaurants":[],"status":true}
>
> D/RestauransActivity: Items = 0

```
call.enqueue(new Callback<RestaurantsListResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<RestaurantsListResponse> call, Response<RestaurantsListResponse> response)
        {
            if(response.isSuccessful())
            {
                data = new ArrayList<>();
                RestaurantsListResponse restaurants = response.body();
                Log.d("RestauransActivity", "response = " + new Gson().toJson(restaurants));
                data = restaurants.getRestaurants();
                Log.d("RestauransActivity", "Items = " + data.size());

                RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);
                adapter = new MyRecyclerViewAdapter(data);
                RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
                recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
                recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
                recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
            }
```

---

```
    public class RestaurantsListResponse
    {
    //...

    @SerializedName("restaurants")
    @Expose
    private List<Restaurant> restaurants = null;

    /...

    public List<Restaurant> getRestaurants()
    {
        return restaurants;
    }

    public void setRestaurants(List<Restaurant> restaurants)
    {
        this.restaurants = restaurants;
    }
}
```

---

```
public class Restaurant
{
   //... fields, some setters and getters
}
```

Comment: What does the JSON look like coming down before it tries to convert into the POJO? It is possible it isn't being deserialized correctly.

Comment: http://puu.sh/uJ0XT/7ac9de14ba.png

Comment: The response you posted in the question has an empty array of restaurants. Is this the actual json or receiving?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/tksG7G8e It looks like this

Answer (score 0):

Everything works fine now. Problem was bad field name in RestApi class.